# create depended dropdownlist using python , streamlit connected with SQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, dropdown, streamlit

i have a streamlit app that is connected to the database (SQL server ) where i have  form that allow the user to insert values  and this form includes 3 `selectbox` that are related between each other (3 columns from the same table), where **based on the selection of the first selectbox the second one display the list, and the same for the relation between second and third**.

Until now i am able to create the 3 selectbox but with no relation between each other.

## code:

```
patternt = r"(?<=')[^,]+?(?=')"
query_street =(
                   r"select distinct street "

                   r"from dbo.info"

                      )    
rows_street = cursor.execute(query_street).fetchall()
rows_street = re.findall(patternt , " ".join([str(s) for s in rows_street]))

                       

 query_bulding =(
                  r"select distinct building "
                  r"from dbo.info"

                )    
rows_building = cursor.execute(query_building).fetchall()
rows_building = re.findall(patternt , " ".join([str(s) for s in rows_building]))

street_input =  st.selectbox("Select street",rows_street)
building_input =  st.selectbox("Select building",rows_building)
```